# Intersection of 2 vectors, logical error

Tags: c, algorithm, vector

I want to write a code (in c) that prints the intersection of two vectors of "N" lenght and cannot print the same number twice. The vectors will be filled with a function, that reads the input ( any number), one by one. And after all, the code needs to print another vector with the intersection between the first two vectors. Until now i wrote the code below, but it has a logical error that i cant solve.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void preencheVetor(int* v, int tamanho){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
        scanf("%d", *(v+i));
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void interVetor(int* v1, int* v2, int tamanho){
    int* v3=malloc(sizeof(int)*tamanho);
    int i1=0;
    int i2=0;
    int i3=0;
    int c=0;
    for(i1=0;i1<tamanho;i1++){
        for(i2=0;i2<tamanho;i2++){
            if((v1[i1])==(v2[i2])){
                *(v3+c)=v2[i2];
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i3=0;i3<tamanho;i3++){
        printf("%d", *(v3+i3));
        printf("\n");
    }   
}

int main(){
int n=0;
printf("Vectors Lenght:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\n\n");
int v1[n];
int v2[n];
preencheVetor(v1, n);
printf("\n\n");
preencheVetor(v2, n);
printf("\n\n");
interVetor(v1, v2, n);
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "intersection of two vectors".  Are the vectors just representations of sets and intersection is set intersection?  If so, you probably want to first remove duplicates from the vectors and may want to sort them in some way to provide a canonical representation of sets (so identical sets will always be represented by identical vectors).  Or do the vectors represent vectors in space and you want to find the point at which they intersect?  In which case you need something completely different...

Comment: In a simple way, i just want to create another vector with the repetition of numbers between the 2 original vectors.

Comment: Please describe this "logical error".

Comment: I dont know, the problem is in the final vector i think ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of vector `v3` is `c` not `tamanho`.  Fix the `for(i3...)` loop.
Other than that, I think your intersection works OK.
It is very inefficient, of course, if the vectors are not sorted.

Comment: Yeah, there were two problems, the one you said and a invalid input format on the scanf, but its working (: